# Transition to next state based on condition if true in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am working on an Agent Based Model. I have a agent of population 100 named bidders (Bidder) on Main agent.

I have a parameter called budget, please see the image below

[image]

Now, I sorted this budget in ascending order for the highest/maximum 3 values using the following code on startup and put the value in a variable inside the agent type Bidder. Please see image,

[image]

Once done, now I want to set up my transition condition,
[image]

I have also tried this.willDoSomething == true but all the agent population goes through this state. As I wanted the the three agents with the 1st three highest budget for the willDoSomething variable to be true, only 3 agent type should have passed through this transition.

[image]